# How to get specific element in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If I have JSON that is:

```
var response = {results: 2938; id: 9283};
```

How can I get id using javascript/jquery?

I tried something like but I can't seem to get what I want (I want to get the number in id):

```
response[1]
```

and

```
response[1].id
```

Comment: A JavaScript object literal is not JSON

Comment: To be more specific, the JSON is a response from a POST that I do.  I save it to a variable response and I want to get that specific element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple:

```
response.id
```

With that being said, your json is invalid,

```
var response = {results: 2938; id: 9283};
```

Use a `,` to separate items not a `;`

```
var response = {results: 2938, id: 9283};
```

And since I love jsfiddle so much, here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/mj84C/).

Comment: I am getting the response as var response = "{results: 2938, id: 9283}"; How do i get the elements then?

Answer (score 4):

Just `response.id`. You don't need anything more.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to use:

```
response.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dynamic func_param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(key);

foreach (var invoicekey in func_param)
{
    var invoice = merchelloHelper.Query.Invoice.GetByKey(Guid.Parse(invoicekey.Value));
}
```